inverse image of Trace mapping from $\mathbb F_{q^m}$ to $\mathbb F_{q}$
Let $T: \mathbb F_{q^m} \to \mathbb F_{q}$, $T(\alpha)=\alpha + \alpha^{q} + \cdots + \alpha^{q^{m-1}}$. It is easy to check that $T$ is epimorphism.
The question: for each element $a \in \mathbb F_q$, how many inverse images of $a$? I guess the answer is $q^m/q$, but I don't know how to prove it. I would appreciate any help!

$T$ is a linear map, yes? By the first isomorphism theorem, the preimage of $a$ is just $a + \ker(T)$, which has $|\ker(T)| = q^{m-1}$ elements, as you guessed.

As, $T: \mathbb F_{q^m} \to \mathbb F_{q}$ is given by, $T(\alpha)=\alpha + \alpha^{q} + \cdots + \alpha^{q^{m-1}}$, now as $T$ is a epimorphism so for each $a \in \mathbb{F}_{q}, T^{-1}(a) \neq \phi$. Now $T(\alpha) = a \iff f(x) = -a + x + x^{q} + \cdots + x^{q^{m-1}} = 0$, has a solution. Now $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{q}[x]$, of degree $q^{m-1}$, so $f(x)$ has degree many roots(As fields are unique factorization domains). That is cardinality of $T^{-1}(a)$ is equal to $q^{m-1}$.
